# Kotlin - reference equality doesn't always work

Tags: kotlin

According to the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html), `===` performs referential equality.

Given the following referential equality comparisons, this doesn't seem to work in all cases:

```
val x = "A"
val y = "A"

println(x === y) // "true"
println("A" === "A") // "true"
```

I would expect both of those cases to return false.

Yet this example returns false as expected:

```
val x = readLine()!! // "A"
val y = readLine()!! // "A"

println(x === y) // "false"
```

So why does referential equality comparison work for the latter case, but not the former?

Comment: Because two equal string literals are likely to be compiled to the same object.

Comment: to add to the link, the difference here is that it is not known at compile time what readLine() will read

Comment: Because it's cached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `===` basically means "are these objects of the same type and do they point to the same memory address?"

In your first example, both `x` and `y` point to a constant `A`, which, as a String constant, there is a single instance of, so they return true.

When you read from a file, an allocation takes place for the string read, and thus, `x` and `y` point to different memory addresses, so they are equal (`==` returns true), but not identical (`===` return false).